# Display port not working (blank screen), hdmi works fine. (Details included)

Tags: displayport

- **Graphics Card:** Gigabyte ARadeon™ RX460 WINDFORCE OC 4G
- **Display:** [Dell U2415 UltraSharp](http://accessories.ap.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=hk&cs=hkdhs1&l=en&s=dhs&sku=391-BBUW&redirect=1)
- **Cable:** AKASA DisplayPort cable. Cheapest I’ve found, link [here](https://goo.gl/3RqAdy).

Is anything wrong with this combination? I can’t even see BIOS when booting my PC. No blinking. Display just says there is no input signal at all. When I connect same graphics card and display using HDMI cable, everything works fine.

Comment: Maybe just a faulty cable.

Comment: Page 40 of the users manual tells you how to change the input port used by the monitor. Have you tried that? http://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_display_projector/esuprt_display/dell-u2415_user%27s%20guide_en-us.pdf Also, that monitor has a display port out connector. You should check that, too.

Comment: changing input port on monitor helped :-) I expected some sort of connected sources auto-detection.